# Looking for suggestions on how to create an enhanced tooltip

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0

currently I am using a tool tip to display information when it hovers over a region on a winform. This works well and I don't have any complaints, but the  boss  want's to display more complex data, that would best be displayed in a grid rather than text.
Is there a way that perhaps I could embed a usercontrol or a datagridview in a tool tip.

thanks

C#, .Net 2.0, windows.Forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's such a thing as an [owner-drawn tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.ownerdraw.aspx). You'd have to handle the painting of the grid yourself. You wouldn't get any interactivity, although a tooltip that lets you click and scroll sounds odd anyway.

If your boss is willing to spend money on this then I can happily recommend the [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/) tooltip control, for its customisability.

Comment: There will be no interaction. But he want's to have the information displayed in rows and columns and the strings are a variety of lengths...I didn't want to mess with a bunch of tabs in order to achieve the effect

Comment: Sure - I'd imagine it would be straightforward to turn on owner drawing, and draw the grid into the tooltip on request.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom control (shouldn't be too hard, just a yellow rectangle with a drop shadow) with a data grid on it. It just needs to fade out when the mouse moves away and get displayed after the mouse rests on it for a couple of seconds.